# Best way to use database connection for every get/post request in .net core web api service

Tags: database, performance, connection

I have .net core web api service. Should i open new connection and close for every get/post request? Or, is there a performance way to use db connection like a global connection variable?

Comment: This might help you edit your question to get more responses: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. You use the AddDbContext extension method to configure your DbContext and it'll automatically create a Scoped instance of the context which is created and disposed with each request:

```
var connection = @"Server=(localdb)\mssqllocaldb;Database=EFGetStarted.AspNetCore.NewDb;Trusted_Connection=True;ConnectRetryCount=0";
    services.AddDbContext<BloggingContext>
        (options => options.UseSqlServer(connection));
```

For a full example visit: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/get-started/aspnetcore/new-db?tabs=visual-studio

Comment: Thank you for your answer. That is exactly i looking for.